# Angular Mat Card is not displaying calculated values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I`m using mat-card in my app and rendering it via ngFor. So content of card is calculated, but values came from this calculations is not rendering at all.

I tried to do some regular output in card, it works fine, when i need to use curly braces, it breaks. Typing something like {{'render this string'}} not working too.

```
<mat-card class="tribe-card" *ngFor="let committee of (committeesList$ | async)">
    <mat-card-header>
       <!-- This is not working -->
       <mat-card-subtitle><p>{{'committee.sName'}}</p></mat-card-subtitle>
       <!-- This is working -->
       <mat-card-title><p>Absolutely regular rendering</p></mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <!-- This is not working -->
    <mat-card-content>{{committee.oActivePhase.sName}}</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

What can be source of this bug and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes: `{{committee.sName}}`

One more thing: use Elvis operator, so null/undefined attributes cause an irrecoverable error:

```html
{{committee?.oActivePhase?.sName}}
```

Comment: This part is under other ngIf, so this always have data. Ok, I got what was wrong.
Problem was in other place of app, I had an error there, so angualr just stopped computing an not rendered this part.